# Issue with displaying letters with descenders

Tags: css, fonts

I'm having this really weird issue with my custom font, everything works except the letters with descenders. Those seem to start on the baseline instead of under it. [Example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8U147.png) 
Is this a issue with the font or something I can solve using css?

Comment: Looks like this is an issue with the font that's been used..

Comment: Okay, so it's not a css issue. Thanks

Comment: No, not at all. `:)`